# How to lock the iPad's screen with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: ios, ipad, keybindings

Is it possible to lock the iPad's screen by using a keyboard shortcut, when using a BT keyboard, or the SmartKeyboard?

Cmd+Shift+Eject as on the Mac does not work. Holding down the Cmd key also does not show any shortcut.

Comment: Consider also: using Assistive Touch!

Comment: That’s what I do as I use a bluetooth keyboard and iPad is on a dock where it’s difficult to press physical sleep button, but I can just tap and be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past, this was **not** possible with a keyboard shortcut. Some third party keyboard has dedicated buttons for locking and more...

Now there are [widely available key shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363884/5472) and Accessability and switch control options to lock the screen on iPadOS.

Answer (score 41):

I was able to figure out <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> seems to work on the new iPad Pro keyboard to lock it.

Comment: Glorious, thank you so much.  As of this writing, this shortcut isn’t present on the Global Keyboard Shortcuts helper dialog in iPadOS 15.1…

Answer (score 2):

Right now it may be possible if you have **`Fn`** key on your keyboard.

Just click **`Fn` + `L`** and the screen will be locked.

This works on my bluetooth keyboard(Logitech K375s), but I'm not sure whether it works on every keyboard.

Comment: It doesn't work on my old Magic Keyboard...